# Resample raster spatial resolution from 5 arc minutes to 1km2

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have the following raster layer:

```
> raster
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2160, 4320, 9331200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

How do I resample the resolution from 5 arc minutes to 1km2?

My understanding is that 1km2 spatial res is equivalent to 30 arc seconds, therefore I would use the solution:
disaggregate(raster, factor = 10).

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/report/s6/s6A.html and https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/raster/html/disaggregate.html

Answer (score 1):

```
library(raster)
#> Warning: package 'raster' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Loading required package: sp
#> Warning: package 'sp' was built under R version 4.0.5
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(r)
rd <- disaggregate(r, fact=c(10,10))
plot(rd
```

[image]

They look the same, but resolution was modified:

```
ncol(r)
#> [1] 10
ncol(rd)
#> [1] 100
Created on 2021-09-23 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```